# Закрыть процесс File.AppendAllText("путь к файлу.txt", содержание файла);

Tags: c#

Я использую в одном классе создание текстового файла и записываю в него что - то через File.AppendAllText("путь к файлу.txt", содержание файла);
Но когда я хочу прочитать содержимое этого файла в другом классе, то возникает ошибка, связанная с тем, что процесс этого файла открыт и поэтому программа не может с ним работать.
Как закрыть процесс, который прописан через File.AppendAllText

Comment: Добавьте описание ошибки. Согласно документации, после выполнения операции записи в файл последний будет закрыт (при условии отсутствия ошибок, но тогда бы Вы получили исключение). И точный путь к файлу, который Вы используете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к и FileStream и StreamWriter, Реализовывают интерфейс IDisposable, то 
можно использовать такую конструкцию,  и будет вам счастье

```
 using (var file = new FileStream("path//file.txt", FileMode.Append))
        using(var writer = new StreamWriter(file,Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write("needed");
        }
```

В итоге, при компиляции этот код выльется в (не точь в точь, но смысл  тот же)

```
 FileStream file = null;
            try
            {
                file = new FileStream("path//file.txt", FileMode.Append);
                StreamWriter writer = null;
                try
                {
                    writer = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8);
                    writer.Write("needed");
                }
                catch { }
                finally
                {
                    writer?.Dispose();
                }

            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                file?.Dispose();
            }
```